# Modernizr.datalistelem returning false in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, spreadsheet, modernizr, datalist

Hi I have created a html page. [link](http://itchyapps.com.au/aherns/ahernsshopping.html)
Here data coming from spreadsheets.google.com. 
Here during load it displaying error.
I found a javascript code there which is indicating that browser will not support. And for this reason my product list also not displaying in dropdown list.

```
if (!Modernizr.datalistelem) {
 alert('This browser does not support all Aherns app functionality - suggest using another browser');
}
```

This is modernizer link
http://modernizr.com/download/#-input-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-elem_datalist-load

Here datalist Element is using for this purpose.

Comment: I don't understand your question, the only errror i can see its a missing element with class name page_header : var header=parent.document.getElementsByClassName('page_header');
header[0].style.display='none'
console.log(header); 
instead in console Modernizr.datalistelem return 
true

Comment: @Infer-on bro try using safari browser that datalist not working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, as you can read [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist), Safari doesn't support `datalist`, so you can only use Modernzr to switch to a [polyfill](https://github.com/miketaylr/jquery.datalist.js)

for that HTML:

```
<input class="destination-list" type="text" placeholder="From:" list="city">
```

---

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.datalistelem,
  nope: ['js/jquery.js', 'js/jquery.datalist.js', 'js/load.datalist.js']
});
```

where `js/load.datalist.js` contains:

```
$('input[list]').datalist();
```

Reference: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-datalist/